# how to edit input type data with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I'm trying to edit my input date, precisally the box of calendary and arrow.
Here my code:

```css
input[type="date"] {
  color: #888;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Date</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="date">
</body>
</html>
```

Here what I want to edit

[image]

Comment: You can't style this. You can replace it to `type=text` and use plugin such as [jquery-ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for the calendar.

Comment: Here is a nice codepen that shows what you can style with css. https://codepen.io/tgrant54/pen/LFblv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible. the browsers creates a `shadow-root` of the calendar which you can not style.

You have the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag added so maybe look as the [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it